# Compare two list of classes in c#

Tags: c#

I have this class:
`.NET Framework 3.5`

```
Class my_class {
 string name;
 int val_1;
 int val_2;
 .
 . 
 .
 int val_n;
}
```

And I have the following lists:

```
List<my_class> list1;
List<my_class> list2;
List<my_class> result1;
List<my_class> result2;
List<my_class> resultEdit;
```

Both `list1`, and `list2` may contain more than **500K to 1 million** object.

`result1` list should contains the objects that are exist on `list1` and not exist on `list2`.

`result2` list should contains the objects that are exist on `list2` and not exist on `list1`.

`resultEdit` should contains the object that are exists on both `list1` and in `list2`, but one of `val_1`, `val_2`,...`val_n` are different between `list1` and `list2`.

Example:

```
List1 = { {"A",1,2,3,4} , {"B",1,2,3,4}, {"C",1,2,3,4} };
List1 = { {"A",1,2,3,4} , {"D",1,2,3,4}, {"C",1,4,3,4} };
```

The results should be:

```
result1 = {{"B",1,2,3,4}};
result2 = {{"D",1,2,3,4}};
resultEdit1 = {{"C",1,2,3,4}};
```

I know there are a lot of ways to do this, but with the large number of items in each lists (more than 500K item in each list) the process time is not good!

So any good, fast way to achieve that?

Note: The processing time is so important for me and the memory also

Comment: It is unique then a HashSet is the obvious alternative, provides amortized O(1) access and O(n) for set operations.  If keeping order is important then you still also need to keep in it a list.

Comment: If standard `Enumerable.Except` with comparer does not work for you (which I assume the case as you've said you can't get reach desired goal with regular implementation) then your question may be too broad for SO and possibly on-topic on one of other more theoretical SE sites.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Guys, the application is a realtime project, so the processing time is so important, and this method we need to call it many times, so I'm asking what's the best and fast way to achieve that!

Comment: How are the data in list1 and list2 populated?  Perhaps there is a way to categorize the data before splitting them into two lists.

Comment: @Hazem if we do not know what you did then how can we suggest where to go? CPU are cheap, do you have constraints? Did you try and you have a performance issue? If you have to intersect million objs in real time then I'd also suggest to better organize them than a...list.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of things missing in the description, but I would do some pre-processing on the data, before comparing:

1. Add a sorting functionality to each element. So, I would have {"A", 1, 2, 3, 4} transferred to an object of <string, int>, where the string is the name ("A"), and the int is the number 1234 (depending on the value of n. If it's too long, just use a string).
2. Now you can sort the elements in a proper data structure (<"A", 1234> would come before <"A", 1235>). I would use a dictionary with a sorted list in each key.
3. Finding the different results is easier now. For example, for <"A", 1234"> in list1, just check is it exists in under the key "A" in list2. This search should now be much faster.

Comment: It seems that the OP has removed the indication that name is a unique property per list.